How to check if a function got overriden by other script?
How to detect that native function such as setTimeout got monkey patched / polyfilled by other script?
One simple approach is to check


console.log(
  String(setTimeout).includes('[native code]') // returns true if native
)



but it's easy to override toString() and trick this code. What's a better way of doing this?

"Assume they haven't been, and if things break, that's on them"? A.k.a. what are you doing that requires knowing this? Because folks should be able to override globals for bog standard, trivial things like debugging and automation, and your code shouldn't need to care.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's true, but my script is likely to run with angular or other framework that patches timers. The problem is they all break the stacktrace and I need to patch the patch if detected

Sounds like you should ask about that instead, because it's incredibly unlikely that Angular etc. break JS Timers. Far too many libraries depend on them for that to make any kind of sense.

they don't break them, they just don't care about preserving stacktrace and I do

Again: sounds like you want to ask about that. No one wins with an XY problem. Just explain what you're trying to achieve with some [mcve] code, talk about what concrete problem you're running into with which actual framework(s), and what you already tried to mitigate it. Because it's quite likely that a solution will be different from what you're trying to do right now.

The only way you can do this is if you have code that runs before the code that does the patching. You can save the value of window.setTimeout in a variable, and then compare them.

A possible heuristic is to convert the built-in function to a string. Built-in functions generally convert to something like function setTimeout() { [native code] } instead of having a real function body. The specific format will depend on the browser, however (my example is for Chrome).

it cannot be fixed from their side because they would need to create some hook that let me execute my callback after setTimeout gets triggered. And by "they" I mean all possible libraries that override the default behavior. I know how it sounds but believe me - it's not an XY problem. I just want to avoid monkey patching every time because I could easily do that and it's not about only setTimeout, that's just an example

@Barmar: that's exactly what my example code is doing. The problem is some libraries such as Angular fake this behavior for some reason https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2e891ad72a6dd4f7f0707a51990cff63ec02f4ce/packages/zone.js/test/common/Promise.spec.ts#L70

Oops, didn't read fully.

The reason it's an XY problem is because maybe there's a solution to your overall goal that doesn't require looking at stack traces, or can skip over these frames in the stack trace. If you explain what you're trying to do with the stack trace that fails, we may be able to help you solve that problem.
